# Found some contradiction in wikipedia about topological space

Tags: general-topology

Given X = {1, 2, 3, 4}, the collection τ = {{}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} of three subsets of X forms a topology of X according to the openset definition.

Then {1} is neighbourhood of element "1", because "a subset U of X is defined to be open if U is a neighbourhood of all points in U".

Then according to axiom 2 of the neighbourhood definition, {1,2} and {1,2,3} are also neighbourhoods of element "1".

Then according to axiom 4 of the neighbourhood definition, {1,2,3} is a neighbourhood of every elements in {1,2}.

But why {1,2,3} is a neighbourhood of element "2", there is no open set that included by {1,2,3} include element "2".

ref:[enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space)

Comment: You are right. $\{1,2,3\}$ is  not a neighborhood of $2$.

Comment: Can some one correct the page in wikipedia?

Comment: Could you please show where on the linked Wikipedia page it is claimed that $\{1,2,3\}$ is a neighbourhood of $2$? It is definitely not a consequence of the neighbourhood axiom 4.

Comment: @chendi Every page on wikipedia has an "Edit" link that you can use to edit the page yourself, right now. You don't even need to sign up for an account.

Comment: No need. I got my answer. Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom $4$ of neighbouhood definition states that:

> Any neighbourhood N of x includes a neighbourhood M of x such that N is a neighbourhood of each point of M.

Which means that there exits some sub-neighbourhood satisfying it, not that every sub-neighbourhood satisfies it.
If $N = \{ 1,2,3\}$, $M=\{1\}$ satisfies this axiom.

Comment: Thank you very much. My english probably is terrible.